# Showing text inside div using button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

This my code.

```html
@helper CreateDiv()
{
    <label>A</label>
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    function SHowDiv()
    {
        alert('@Html.Raw(CreateDiv().ToString())');
    }
</script>

<h2>Index</h2>

<input type="button" value="ShowDiv" onclick="SHowDiv()" />

<div id="div1">
</div>
```

I want to show "A" inside div1 on button click. But it is giving me error. Where i am doing wrong? Please help. I have used alert just to check whether the button click is working or not.

Comment: _"But it is giving me error"_ WHAT ERROR!

Comment: 'SHowDiv' is undefined. This error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function SHowDiv()
    {
      document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML = "Hello JavaScript!";
    }
</script>

<input type="button" value="ShowDiv" onclick="SHowDiv()" />
```

Comment: I can not do that way. I have to use @helper